# How to implement custom login page with Okta and React Native

Tags: react-native, okta

I want to create a custom login page in Okta. I'm using Expo, React Native and @okta/okta-react-native npm module. I'm not sure is it possible to create custom web component which will replace existing default Okta sign in page. All Okta custom sign in documentation is designed for web technologies, but not for React Native.

I tried to customize it with @okta/okta-signin-widget but seems like it only works for React.js.

This is my Okta clinet:

```
export const tokenClient = new TokenClient({
  issuer: 'https://dev-xxxxx.okta.com',
  client_id: '0oanuaxae4356',
  redirect_uri: 'exp://localhost:19000/+expo-auth-session'
});
```

Comment: This is not possible at the moment AFAIK. You have to do browser redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I can use directly Okta Authentication API so it's solved!